# Google Maps V3 .getBounds().lat() returns Window

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm running a Django app using GMaps V3. I'm plotting markers on the map, but due to the size of the dataset, I don't want to render them all, just those visible in the current viewport.

I'm using `var top = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat()` to get the bounds of the viewport in 2 different cases, and then filtering all my points to only display those with latitude below `top`.

The first time I run this returns what I'd expect, a latitude like `52.xxx`, but the second time, it returns `Window`. I'm also running the same sort of function for the left, right and bottom of the viewport, and both times they return the same (expected) results.

It's difficult to give exact code as it's very dependent on the rest of the app, but as an example:

```
function getMapBounds(map){
    var r = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    var l = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
    var t = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    var b = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();

    MB = [r, l, t, b];
}
console.log(MB)
```

returns:

```
[-6.182485199047846, -6.294923400952143, 53.32952272076843, 53.28244090019188]
```

whereas:

```
function plotPoints(map){
    right = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    left = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
    top = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
    bottom = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
    console.log(right);
    console.log(left);
    console.log(top);
    console.log(bottom);
}
```

returns:

```
-6.204080899047881
-6.316519100952178
Window {stop: function, open: function, alert: function, confirm: function, prompt: function…}
53.326276765171606
```

The numbers are identical (as they should be, it's the same viewport) except for my `top` variable. I've copy and pasted the code to ensure they're identical in both cases, and looked for duplicate variable names which could be causing issues, but nothing found. Tried changing variable names and reordering functions but no luck

Any ideas why they're different and potential solutions would be greatly welcomed!

Comment: Could it be that the map is not fully loaded? Or is this being called within a load callback/ promise?

Comment: Have a look at this question, seems to have a similar issue to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429943/google-map-api-v3-getbound-doesnt-returns-the-lat-lng-bounds-of-the-curren

Comment: `top` is a reserved word in Javascript, don't use it: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: @Lissy I don't think so, when that happens I get `undefined`, and the fact that the other variables have value suggests that the map has fully loaded

Comment: @duncan Thanks! I usually code in python and wasn't aware of that. Changed to `above` and it's working great now